# ADO Recordset filter comparing two fields

Tags: vb6, adodb, recordset

How can I filter a recordset by comparing two fields?

For a given ADO Recordset with n fields (Field1, Field2,...,Fieldn)

I used to filter a field against a value:

```
rs.Filter = "Field1 = 'something'"
```

But what I need to do is something like this:

```
rs.Filter = "Field1 = Field2"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you try it? Because I'm pretty sure I've done this in (far distant) past.

Comment: yes, I tried, but I get this error "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another."

Comment: If Field1 and Field2 types are defferent try casting one field type to another like rs.Filter = "Field1 = CStr(Field2)" if Field1 type is String.

Comment: Looks like we cannot compare two fields, only a field against a literal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The criteria string is made up of clauses in the form FieldName-Operator-Value
>
> Value is the value with which you will compare the field values (for example, 'Smith', #8/24/95#, 12.345, or $50.00). Use single quotes with strings and pound signs (#) with dates. For numbers, you can use decimal points, dollar signs, and scientific notation. If Operator is LIKE, Value can use wildcards. Only the asterisk (*) and percent sign (%) wild cards are allowed, and they must be the last character in the string. Value cannot be null.

This suggests that comparing fields to each other is not supported.  `Value` must be a literal.